# Refinement of Schwarz's Lemma

Tags: analysis

The following is a refinement of Schwarz's Lemma. I am trying to prove for $$|z| \leq R$$ that
$$|f(z)|\leq M \left(\frac{M|z|+|a|R}{|a||z|+MR}\right)$$ where $$f(z)$$ is analytic in $$|z|\leq R$$ such that $$|f(z)| \leq M$$ on $z=R$ and $f(0)=a$ where $|a|< M$. I know we want to take a derivative, but still have not come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $F(z)=M\left(\frac{f(Rz)-a}{\overline{a}f(Rz)-M^2}\right)$,$\hspace{0.3cm}$ $|z|\leq 1$ $\hspace{0.3cm} \Longrightarrow|Rz|\leq R \hspace{0.5cm}$

Let  $$\hspace{0.2cm} \overline{a}f(Rz)-M^2=0 \hspace{0.1cm}\\ \Longleftrightarrow |a||f(Rz)|= M^2 \Longleftrightarrow |f(Rz)|=\frac{M^2}{|a|}>M$$ $|F(z)| \leq M\hspace{0.3cm} $ on $\hspace{0.3cm}|z|=R \hspace{0.1cm} \Longleftrightarrow |f(Rz)|\leq M \hspace{0.3cm}$ on $\hspace{0.3cm}|z|\leq 1 $ $$\Longrightarrow|\overline{a}f(Rz)| \leq |a|M <M^2 \Longrightarrow \overline{a}f(Rz)-M^2\neq 0$$ in $|z| \leq 1 $. $$$$So, $F(z)$ is analytic in $|z|\leq 1$. $$F(0)=M\left(\frac{f(0)-a}{\overline{a}f(0)-M^2}\right)=0$$ $$ $$Let $f(Rz)=w$, $\hspace{0.4cm}w \leq M\hspace{0.3cm}$ on $\hspace{0.3cm}|z|=1$. $\hspace{0.3cm}$ Now suppose $$\left|M \frac{w-a}{\overline{a}w-M^2}\right|^2=M^2 \frac{|w|^2 + |a|^2-2\hspace{0.1cm} Re(\overline{a}w)}{M^4+|a|^2 |w|^2-2\hspace{0.1cm} Re(M^2 \overline{a}w)}\leq 1$$ $\Longleftrightarrow M^2 |w|^2+M^2|a|^2\leq M^4+|a|^2 |w|^2$ $$\Longleftrightarrow M^2 |a|^2-|a|^2|w|^2\leq M^4-M^2 |w|^2 $$ $$\Longleftrightarrow |a|^2\leq M^2 \Longleftrightarrow |a| \leq M $$ $$$$So,$\hspace{0.3cm}F(z) \leq1 \hspace{0.2cm}$ on $\hspace{0.2cm}|z|=1.$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$ By Schwarz's Lemma, we have $|F(z)|
 \leq |z|$, $\hspace{0.2cm}$so $$M\left|\frac{f(Rz)-a}{\overline{a}f(Rz)-M^2}\right| \leq|z| \Longrightarrow \left|\frac{\frac{f(Rz)}{M}-\frac{a}{M}}{1-\frac{{a}}{M}\frac{f(Rz)}{M}}\right|\hspace{0.3cm} \leq |z|$$ $$ \Longrightarrow \frac{\frac{|f(Rz)|}{M}-\frac{|a|}{M}}{1-\frac{{|a|}}{M}\frac{|f(Rz)|}{M}}\hspace{0.3cm} \leq |z|$$ $$\Longrightarrow \frac{|f(Rz)|}{M}-\frac{|a|}{M} \hspace{0.2cm}\leq \hspace{0.1cm}\ |z|-\frac{|z||a||f(Rz)|}{M^2}$$ $$\Longrightarrow \frac{|f(Rz)|}{M}+\frac{|z||a||f(Rz)|}{M^2} \hspace{0.2cm}\leq \hspace{0.1cm}\ |z|+\frac{|a|}{M}$$ $$\Longrightarrow |f(Rz)| \left(\frac{1}{M}+\hspace{0.2cm}\frac{|z||a|}{M^2}\right)\leq \hspace{0.1cm}\ |z|+\frac{|a|}{M}$$ $$\Longrightarrow |f(Rz)|\leq \frac{|z|+\frac{|a|}{M}}{\frac{1}{M}+\frac{|z||a|)}{M^2}}\hspace{0.3cm}= M\left( \frac{M|z|+|a|}{M+|z||a|}\right)$$ Now let $\hspace{0.2cm} u=
Rz$, $\hspace{0.3cm}|z|\leq 1$, $\hspace{0.2cm}$then $\hspace{0.2cm} z=\frac{u}{R}$, $\hspace{0.2cm}$and $\hspace{0.2cm}|u|\leq R$.$\hspace{0.3cm}$ So, $$|f(u)|\leq M \left(\frac{M\frac{|u|}{R}+|a|}{M+|a|\frac{|u|}{R}}\right)=M\left( \frac{M|u|+|a|R}{|a||u|+MR}\right)\hspace{0.2cm}$$ Therefore, the result follows replacing $u$ with $z$. $\hspace{0.9cm}\Box$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$F(z)=M\left(\frac{f(Rz)-a}{\overline{a}f(Rz)-M^2}\right)$$ If $f$ is analytic in $|z|\leq 1$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ in $|z|\leq 1$, then $$|f(z)|\leq \frac{(1-|a|)|z^2|+|bz|+|a|(1-|a|)}{|a|(1-|a|)|z^2|+|bz|+(1-|a|)}$$ for $|z|\leq 1$ where $a=f(0)$ and $b=f '(0)$. Thus $$f(z)=\frac{a+\frac{b}{1+a}z-z^2}{1-\frac{b}{1+a}z-az^2}$$